# Why is my local IP address being denied by Google Time Zone API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-maps-api-3

UPDATE - I got it to work by using my IPv6 address. Google didn't like my IPv4 address for some reason.

I'm using the Google Cloud Time Zone web service to get a time zone.
If I have no restrictions it works fine, but if I set my restrictions to my local IP address given by https://whatismyipaddress.com/ and put that into my restrictions as seen in the picture below (not actual IP address shown), I get a denied access message when running the service to get a time zone?

Can anyone help explain why?
According to my other post: [Why is my Google Cloud Time Zone API request being denied for the time zone API but ok with other services like maps and autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76124293/1186050)

geocodezip says I have to use an IP address restriction for a web service, not a referrer. So I created a new key and just used a single IP restriction, but this still denies me!

[image]

Here is my code to run the web service.

```js
const url = environment.timeZoneUrl + '?location=' + this.latitude.value + ',' + this.longitude.value + '&timestamp=' + Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000).toString() + '&key=' + environment.googleTimeZoneApiKey;
const timeZoneResult = await fetch(url, {
  method: 'GET'
});
const timeZone = await timeZoneResult.json();

if (timeZone.status !== 'OK') {
  this.alertService.danger('Error fetching timezone: ' + timeZone.errorMessage);
  this.loading = false;
  return;
}
```

Comment: 1) Include your code. 2) Where is the code running? 3) Are you using the IP address of where the code is running? Your post is confusing, more details are required. The IP address in your post is a southern California residential internet provider and I doubt an actual web service.

Comment: 1.) I'll post my code above. 2.) code is running on my machine at home, but I also have a dev and prod server that I'll need to eventually add  3.) I think so, I fetched my IP address from https://whatismyipaddress.com and that's the one I used in the IP restrictions section. Is this not correct? How do I get my IP address?

Comment: Please provide enough details so that we do not need a dialog. What is the code running on? Inside the browser or a web application.

Comment: I just got it to work! As I stepped through my code above, I looked at the error message that came back from the Google service and in the message it said what IP address was trying to access their server and which refferer was used. It didn't show my IPv4 address but my IPv6 address. So I used that as the IP restriction and now it works! Google didn't lie my IPv4 address. No sure why? It also showed my refferer as https//localhost:4200/

Comment: This is why details are important. The reason your IPv4 address did not work is that your system is using IPv6 if available. The endpoint that you are calling, which you do not include in your post, probably resolves with both `A` and `AAAA` resource records.